# Java Dictionary Objects & Array/Linked List

Tags: java, dictionary, multidimensional-array, linked-list

I have a player class, these players have attributes to a Statbook, and that Statbook has 130 attributes that are of the Dictionary class. I want to find the most efficient way to group these players into a team (team class) and I want to know what to use: multidimensional array, linked list, etc. I know that i can use the Enumerate method to populate whatever it is that I end up using, but I need help figuring out what to use.

Thanks.

(Note: This is the code posted in the comments)

```
class Player
{
    Statbook stats;
    String name = "";

    public Player(String n)
    {
        name = n;
        stats = new Statbook();
    }

    public Statbook getStats()
    {
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for the Player class?

Comment: class Player 
{
 Statbook stats;
 String name = "";

 public Player(String n) 
 {
  name = n;
  stats = new Statbook();
 }

 public Statbook getStats() 
 {
  return stats;
 }
}

Statbook is also of Dictionary class

Comment: Are you saying that each `Player` is about 130 `Dictionary` objects, or that you have 130 `Player` objects, each consisting of a `Dictionary` instance?

Comment: Each player has 130 dictionary objects as attributes

Comment: Im sorry, I worded that wrong. Each player has an attribute for a Statbook, and that Statbook contains the stats. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, how are you expecting to group these objects into a team class? Is it based on some key-value pair in the `Dictionary`? Something else? You're looking for an efficient way to iterate over the `Player` objects and add them to a `Team`? Or the best way to store them on the `Team`?

Comment: Thats what I'm asking is how to put these players in a team.

Comment: I have a team class, a player class, main, and a Statbook class. The stat book contains the stats, and each player has a stat book. Now I want to put those players into a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HashSet inside the Team class to store all the players on the team:

```
class Team
{
    private Set<Player> teamMembers = null;

    public Team()
    {
        teamMembers = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player p)
    {
        teamMembers.add(p);
    }

    //And so on...
}
```